# php tiny url not linking correctly. My website url gets appended to tinyurl.com and I get a 404 error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

This is my tiny url function

```
private function getTinyUrl($url) {
    return file_get_contents("http://tinyurl.com/api-create.php?url=".$url);
}
```

the output is something like  http://tinyurl.com/nj76pbs so thats good.

But when I use the url, it takes me to

```
tinyurl.com/mywebsite.com/code?=fqhfkqhiurhg98y
```

and i get a 404 not found. What to do?

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking it's because your **$url** doesn't contain "http://" or "https://". Because of this, when tinyURL attempts a redirect, it stays within the tinyurl domain. Does your $url variable have http or https? If it always wont, you can just add it to the file_get_contents call.

Also, file_get_contents won't work on all servers. Sometimes it's restricted. I'd recommend attempting to do this with CURL if you get the chance.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the http://, https:// in front of the URL. You can possible add a check in your function to auto prefix this if needed.